# Select Parent node in nested data set

Tags: mysql, data-structures

Have teh follwoing query which is fine and dandy...

```
SELECT
    `node`.`site_pages_id` AS `page_id` ,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`parent`.`site_pages_id` SEPARATOR '/') AS `path` ,
    IFNULL( CONCAT( '/' , GROUP_CONCAT(`parent`.`url` SEPARATOR '/') ) , '/' ) AS `url`
FROM
    `site_pages` AS `node`
LEFT JOIN
    `site_pages` AS `parent`
ON
    `node`.`lft_limit` BETWEEN `parent`.`lft_limit` AND `parent`.`rgt_limit`
GROUP BY
    `node`.`site_pages_id`
ORDER BY
    `node`.`lft_limit` ASC
```

produces the following

```
1, 1,     /
2, 1/2,   /about-us
8, 1/2/8, /about-us/meet-the-team
3, 1/3,   /web
5, 1/5,   /print
6, 1/6,   /branding
7, 1/7,   /contact-us
```

All sweet.

I'd like to select the immediate parent and just the immediate parent for each node.

My feeble attempts at doing so without a nasty subquery fail misearably (not much better with TBO).

Tips muchly appreciated

Comment: able to provide some sample of expected output?

Comment: sure. from those tuples I'd like one extra field with values NULL,1,2,1,1,1,1 (in same order as previous list). Obviously it would have to work at any depth so if i had a record showing 1/2/8/15/76 (5 deep) I'd like 15 to be selected as the parent.

Comment: Are you able to publish a sub-set of the database table schema?

Answer (score 0):

No probs Martin...

```
page_id url            lft_limit   rgt_limit
1,      NULL,          1,          14,
2,      about-us,      2,          5,
3,      web,           6,          7,
5,      print,         8,          9,
6,      branding,      10,         11,
7,      contact-us,    12,         13,
8,      meet-the-team, 3,          4,
```